# how to know various spark application statistics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

Spark Job:
//DATA READ/LOAD

```
val df1 = spark.sql("select colList from table1")
val df2 = spark.sql("select colList from table2")
```

//DATA PROCESSING/TRANSFORMATION

```
val df1_filter = df1.filter("cond")
val df2_filter = df1.filter("cond")
val transformation1 = df1_filter.join(df2_filter,joinCondition)
```

//DATA SAVE/WRITE

```
transformation1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").option("quote", "\u0000").save(hdfs_location)
```

QUESTION:
-Is there a way to find out approximate time the job takes to read, process and write the data separately.

the reason for the ask is to approximately find out the time it takes for a bigger dataset by running the job on a sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

RUN it and look at Spark UI for SparkContext when running or via Spark History Server.

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom, I know that by using resource manager, we can get to know the overall time(for all phases) of the application, but not individually for each phase. I've also tried SparkUI, where its a bit more detailed compared to resource manager but is still not a full solution for what I'm specifically looking for.

Comment: I felt it was good enough and this is what most use. So  if no other answer comes then I think you may need to asdume this is the best possible. Let us wait.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the execution plan by running explain plan. But it won't give you any idea about the actual runtime. Its specially tricky with join which depends on lots of things on big data set. Once the job is complete or running, you can check the progress in Spark UI.

Comment: thanks @tanveer, we could only get to see the time taken for each spark "action" triggered in the application individually. But i wanted to see more statistics for each transformation applied in each spark action(i think that's one step further than what sparkUI offers).

Comment: ok got you. There are ways to get more granular level detail on spark transformation using SparkListener. It sends lots of information back to driver for detail analysis. Youtube videos from Spark Summit might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoQ8m-kM_ZY and try Luca Canali's sparkMeasure tool